# How to move login form to navigation bar

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I am currently dealing with a problem i have been trying to solve through 'learn by doing', but i am getting no where and almost on the edge of leaving it alone and let it run the way i know it works.

**The way it works now:**
Currently i have scarfolded the whole identity area from asp.net, the login and registration both runs in separate views

**The way i want it:**
The login should be placed in the navigation bar, but to do so i need the model to paste in the username & password. If i use a model in _LoginPartial the registration does not work. Currently i can move the login form to navigation bar and login/logout as normal using the form, but then i am no longer allowed to register as it want the loginmodel for my registration page.

I can add other code if needed, but they are more or less default scarfolded classes.

[image: Picture Illustration]

#### _LoginPartial

```
@inject SignInManager<User> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<User> UserManager
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using TVScreenViewer.Models.Identity
@model TVScreenViewer.Areas.Identity.Pages.Account.LoginModel

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new {area = ""})" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserAsync(User).Result.Name!</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a>
                    <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block" style="padding: 4px 24px; text-align: left;">Logout</button>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <form asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login" method="post" class="navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <div asp-validation-summary="All" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="row">
            <div style="margin: 0rem 1rem">
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="Input.Username"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Username" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div>
                <input class="form-control form-control-sm" asp-for="Input.Password"/>
                <span asp-validation-for="Input.Password" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div style="margin: 0rem 1rem">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Log in</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

    @*<a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Login">Login</a>*@
    <a asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a>
}

@section Scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial"/>
}
```

Comment: did you try ViewModel ?

Comment: @Haroonnasir i did try using a ViewModel when i wanted to load the registration view in another view, then it gave it nullpointer reference

Answer (score -1):

### Finding UI:

Here's a sample in bootstrap 3, which is a login form as your need:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/examples/jumbotron/

and another in v4 which is a search bar:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/examples/sticky-footer-navbar/

you can inspect element:
[image]

and copy this part (depending on version it may differ
[image]

### Coding (The Actual Issue)

The login it self is not something special
you can use old html form , or MVC beginForm and set the action to send data to Account page... authentication perform over server, and server assign cookies, so it doesn't matter as long as you send the data to the server. and you need two input depending on your model, can be Username & Password,

Also these: `asp-page` and `asp-for` ... are new to me, i do not remember seeing them anywhere, make sure you are using either `@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })` kind of rezor supported field, or `<input name="">` html input with `name` attribute

Also here's default form by Microsoft on .NetBased MVC:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
```

### Default Microsoft Code for Login

**Note**
I noticed you are using Core MVC due to this line `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity`, which it's template may be different from .netframwork template, but the concept should be same

```
@using OpenAndDelete.Models
@model LoginViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Log in";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Use a local account to log in.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <div class="checkbox">
                            @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                            @Html.LabelFor(m => m.RememberMe)
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Log in" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <p>
                    @Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register")
                </p>
                @* Enable this once you have account confirmation enabled for password reset functionality
                    <p>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword")
                    </p>*@
            }
        </section>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <section id="socialLoginForm">
            @Html.Partial("_ExternalLoginsListPartial", new ExternalLoginListViewModel { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl })
        </section>
    </div>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: hi deadManN, thank you for your time, sorry for the delay. the asp-for and asp-page is for an asp.net core project. This project is no longer relevant as i could not use umbraco with asp.net core, so i had to start over with asp.net - but helpful, thanks

Comment: Ah well i never got to use it, I wished to start it, but at that time it wasn't mature and some driver was missing, my company still using .net framework based version too, so It didn't happen that I got to see them

Comment: Do you use umbraco also then?

Comment: @Lasse never hear of it (until now).... we write systems from scratches...